# Bash: write on device then read from it

Tags: bash, device, read-write

I'm developing a very small program with a weight sensor connected to S0. Here is how I initialize the serial port :

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 min 60 time 1 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke parenb -ixon
```

I have tested several manners to write to the device and then read from it :

```
echo IDN? >> /dev/ttyS0
read -t1 output < /dev/ttyS0   # waits for ever here.
```

I've also tried :

```
echo IDN? >> /dev/ttyS0 && read -t1 output < /dev/ttyS0  # waits too
```

But unsuccess. In one line, it doesn't change anything.

```
until read -t1 < /dev/ttyS0; do
    echo IDN? > /dev/ttyS0
done
identity=$(echo $REPLY | tr -d $'\r')
```

This works when the device is connected.

---

For my tests, I did this and it worked:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyS0 &
[1] 9188
$ echo IDN? >> /dev/ttyS0
HBM-xxxyyyzzz$
```

---

The three manners I've tried are unsuccessful. Maybe because the device answers quicker than the bash interprets ? If it's the case, how can I dodge this to have a perfect timed answer from the device ?

What I actually am searching for, is if the device doesn't answer within 1 second, then skip the read, but if it's reading at 200ms, then continue without waiting for the 800 last ms

Comment: But what should happen if read occurs after 200ms but less than 1 sec?

Comment: @Samuel As soon as it's less than 1 second it should stop the read and go to the next line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening the device in read/write mode should work.

```
exec 3<> /dev/ttyS0
echo "IDN?" >&3
read -t1 output <&3
```

Opening the file with `exec` like this means the file stays open across multiple commands, rather than being opened and closed by each command.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much :)

Comment: How do you close the device afterwards?

Comment: If the script ends, the file will be closed automatically. You can close it explicitly (I think) with `exec 3<>-`.